# How does spark reads text format files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I have a dataset in S3 in text format(.gz) and I am using spark.read.csv to read the file into spark.

This is about 100GB of data but it contains 150 columns. I am using only 5 columns (so I reduce the breadth of the data) and I have selecting only 5 columns.

For this kind of scenario, does spark scans the complete 100GB of data or it smartly filters only these 5 columns without scanning all the columns(like in columnar formats)?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
imp_feed = spark.read.csv('s3://mys3-loc/input/', schema=impressionFeedSchema, sep='\t').where(col('dayserial_numeric').between(start_date_imp,max_date_imp)).select("col1","col2","col3","col4")
```

Comment: Please add your code which reads the data from S3, and select the columns.

Comment: Are you joking? CSV is *not* a columnar format, you have to parse it sequentially, byte-after-byte, just to detect the column/record delimiters. Plus, a GZip compressed file must be decompressed sequentially, bit-after-bit. Plus, AFAIK, S3 files are not designed for random access.

Comment: yes, that's what my fear is. We have our daily loads into S3 and they are text and GZip format. So, basically it completely sits in spark (morever, gzip files grow into 5 to 6 times after it gets unzipped)

Answer (score 0):

make step 1 of your workflow the process of reading in the CSV file and saving it as snappy compressed ORC or parquet files.

then go to whoever creates those files and tell them to stop it. At the very least, they should switch to Avro + Snappy, as that's easier to split up the initial parse and migration to a columnar format.